# How to display [not generate] line numbers of files in side by side diff in unix?

Tags: shell, unix, diff, line-numbers, sdiff

I have 2 files for which i want to diff side by side using the following command with the line numbers:

```
diff -y abc1.txt abc2.txt
```

The above command just prints the side by side diff but doesn't display the line numbers associated with the files.

I even tried:

```
diff -y --unchanged-line-format="" --new-line-format=":%dn: %L" abc1.txt abc2.txt
```

But it gives some format conflict exception. Is there any way to do it ? I have searched a lot but couldn't find any solutions for it. I can't use third party tools just for your information. Any brilliant ideas are highly appreciated.

**NOTE:**

*I want the file numbers present of the file itself and not the line numbers generated by piping to cat -n etc.. Lets say, i am doing diff using "--suppress-common-l‌​ines" then the line numbers should be omitted which are not shown in the diff. I want to display the line numbers associated with the files. I don't want to generate line numbers in my diff output*

Comment: did you try leaving out `--unchanged-line-format=""` ? Good luck.

Comment: I think you are looking for `--line-format=LFMT` (applies to all input lines) instead of `--new-line-format=` (applies to just the `new` file) as I read it.

Comment: Do you mean something like `diff <(cat -n abc1.txt) <(cat -n abc2.txt)` ?

Comment: Superb Walter ! I think you gave the correct answer but what if we are doing a recursive diff between folders in that case how to deal with it ? For example: For the scenario, diff -ry folder1 folder2